# Como configurar o schema_search_path no ambiente de test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testes-de-unidade, rspec

Quando executo o comando rake spec --trace eu tenho o erro a abaixo. Me parece que o rake não cria o schema que desejo no ambiente de test por não identificar minha configuração de schema no database.yml. Andei pesquisando e vi que posso fazer uma tarefa automatizada para criar o schema antes de criar as tabelas, mas fiquei pensando que isso deve ser um problema comum para muitas pessoas. Porque o rake não está lendo minhas configurações no database.yml de schema_search_path? Acredito que deve ter uma maneira correta e mais fácil de fazer isso. Alguma idéia

**DATABASE.YML**

```
test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: sist_teste
  schema_search_path: adm_sist
  username: postgres
  password: postgres
  host: localhost
```

**ERRO:**

```
rake spec --trace
** Invoke spec (first_time)
** Invoke spec:prepare (first_time)
** Execute spec:prepare
** Invoke test:prepare (first_time)
** Invoke db:test:prepare (first_time)
** Invoke db:abort_if_pending_migrations (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
[deprecated] I18n.enforce_available_locales will default to true in the future. If you really want to skip validation of your locale you can set I18n.enforce_available_locales = false to avoid this message.
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:abort_if_pending_migrations
** Execute db:test:prepare
** Invoke db:test:load (first_time)
** Invoke db:test:purge (first_time)
** Invoke environment 
** Invoke db:load_config 
** Execute db:test:purge
** Execute db:test:load
** Invoke db:test:load_schema (first_time)
** Invoke db:test:purge 
** Execute db:test:load_schema
** Invoke db:schema:load (first_time)
** Invoke environment 
** Invoke db:load_config 
** Execute db:schema:load
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::InvalidParameterValue: ERROR:  invalid value for parameter "search_path": "adm_sist"
DETAIL:  schema "adm_sist" does not exist
: SET search_path TO adm_sist
```